# Azure Container Access Information

Tags: azure-storage

I need to know how can I restrict access to Azure Storage containers/blobs for certain roles like I want users with Admin role to access container A & B and I want users with HR role to access only container B and not A, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at **SAS**, shared access signature provides you with a way to grant limited access to objects in your storage account to other clients, without exposing your account key. It's through the setup of policies, checkout the below screenshot(it can be done via code or Azure portal):[image]

More Details about SAS can be found here: `https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/manage-stored-access-policies-for-storage-accounts-from-within-the-azure-portal/`

Comment: Thanks Adam however will it cover my scenario if I want A to access and B to restrict.

Comment: Check RBAC using custom roles: Create a custom role in Azure Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) if none of the built-in roles meet your specific access needs. Custom roles can be created using Azure PowerShell, Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI), and the REST API. Just like built-in roles, you can assign custom roles to users, groups, and applications at subscription, resource group, and resource scopes. Custom roles are stored in an Azure AD tenant and can be shared across subscriptions.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles